# Save robospice request result saved in sqllite freeze UI

Tags: android, database, sqlite, robospice

Im using Robospice (best lib so far for me) with Sping ang Gson to communicate with my webservices - simple, clean and working good. Now I want store my data in sql database - eg for offline mode. My problem is how to combine robospice with ormlite or how to use robospice extension for ormlite.

So far Ive created this

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

private void performRequest() {
    MyRequest request = new MyRequest();
    spiceManager.execute(request, request.createCacheKey(),
            DurationInMillis.ONE_MINUTE, new MyRequestListener());
}

private class MyRequestListener implements
        RequestListener<MyDaoList> {
    @Override
    public void onRequestFailure(SpiceException e) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestSuccess(MyDaoList myDaoList) {

        RuntimeExceptionDao<MyDao, Integer> myDao =  mDatabaseHelper.getMyDataDao();
        for (MyDap mDao : myDaoList) {
            myDao.createIfNotExists(mDao);
        }

        ...
    }
 }
}
```

works fine, but not perfect. Data is downloaded, and saved in my sql database. But this solution freeze my UI when a lot of data need to be saved. How can I avoid this freeze?

I have checked robospice samples with sqllite but I have problems with samples and so far looks like it is not finished extension.

Answer (score 0):

UI freeze because `onRequestSuccess` method is called on UI thread (and it's perfectly normal) and saving data takes some time. So you should create new thread (or AsyncTask) in `onRequestSuccess` and save data to DB in this new thread.